# Hexadecimal occurrence counting

Tags: php, hex

> Write a PHP program with a function that given a value $n in input
>   counts how many different number exist with all of the digits 0,1, and
>   A present at least once for hexadecimal values from 1 to $n digits.

I don't understand what this problem is fundamentally asking for.

Let's say 1 to $n = 500. Are we counting the occurances of 0, 1, and A used in a hexadecimal anywhere from 1 to 500?
I just can't seem to wrap my head around what is being asked to be counted.

Comment: as far as I understood the question you have to count the numbers that contains all of the three "letters". So you have to count the numbers that contains in hex 0,1 AND A.

Comment: Unless you have a specific programming issue, this question is likely to get closed. It's not a place up interpret alignments, ask your professor.

Comment: Hint: "hexadecimal values from 1 to $n digits" == `for($i=0,$max=pow(16,$n); $i<$max; $i++0 { ... }` and I strongly recommend not using `$n = 500;` unless you have a few Dyson Spheres and several billion years to wait for your program to finish.

Comment: I'd wager that you could solve this far more simply by expressing it as a combinatorics problem than brute-forcing and evaluating all possible combinations.

Comment: Lastly, homework questions are generally frowned upon by StackOverflow. Asking for a solution is a true faux pas, but you've asked us to clarify your instructor's intent which is not something we can authoritatively answer. You'd be better served asking your instructor/TA/classmate to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way I read it, you need to figure out how many different numbers between 1 and $n contain `0 AND 1 AND A` when written in hexadecimal form. You're not counting how many times each character shows up, but rather how many times all three characters show up at once.